# EF6 Schema and EDM-Designer with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to import and use the new schemas in VS2010 to develop a .NET 4 application? We want to write a application with EF 6 but not all developer have VS2012 - and our office can not buy the newest version in the moment.

A bug in EF4.4 is the reason that we change to the newest source-code of EF and compile them but the EDM-Designer use still the Edmx-Version 2.

The same with the tags in app.config - they not regnonize

Have someone a idea how we can reach the goal?